# Using two different tables in same view

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to do a simple application, but I'm not able to write the views correctly so I can use different tables in a same view.

I have two tables, Sales and SalesLine. Each Sale has many SalesLines. What I'm trying to do is to add a Sale, and in the same page add different SalesLines. In the C# code, each Sale object has an EntitySet of SalesLines.

The HTML code to add a new Sale is the following:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>



        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.N_Factura) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.N_Factura) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.N_Factura) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fecha) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fecha) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fecha) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        <%:Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Proveedor,(ViewData["SelectList"] as SelectList)) %>
          </div>



        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

I want to put in the same page some way to add new SalesLines in this page, so I can fill them and add both Sales and SalesLines by clicking on the Create link. I'm trying to put here a default SalesLine that appears automatically, and then a link that can be used to add other SalesLines if needed, using AJAX (I know it's easier in Java, at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

To Bring data from 2 tables in the same view, User a ViewModel. It is a simple class which you use specifically for this View.

```
public class SalesViewModel
{
  public Sales Sale { set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<SalesLine> Detail{ set;get;}

  public SalesViewModel()
  {
    if(this.Sale==null)
       this.Sale=new Sales();
    if(this.Details==null)
       this.Details=new List<Sales>();
  }    
}
```

Return that to your View

```
public ActionResult GetSales(int id)
{
  SalesViewModel vm=new SalesViewModel();
  vm.Sale=dbContext.Sales.Where(x=x.Id=id);
  vm.Details=dbContext.SalesLine.Where(x=x.SaleId=id);

  return View(vm);

}
```

Your View will be stongly typed to this viewmodel;

```
@model SalesViewModel 

@Model.Sale.Id
/// remaining form elements
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but still don't know how to refer to the detail list in the view. I want to add in the same view code to add a new sale line.

Comment: @amal: To display the detail, you can loop thru the Model.Details property. to add new item. Either you can bring a new form via ajax or redirect to a "Create" form.

Comment: thank you, I will try and tell! I'm having a lot of problems with asp sintaxis for writing HTML code :s

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. Can't find out how to use partial viwe to add new SalesLines. Can anyone give me an example of how to do this? thnx

Comment: @amal: Call a partial view for create on a model dialog(  jQuery UI is an option).